# .htaccess Redirecting domain.com/subfolder/index.html to domain.com/subfolder/

Tags: .htaccess, web, seo, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I want to redirect domain sub folder `index.html` to it's root directory

Example

```
current: https://example.com/en/index.html 
expected: https://example.com/en/
```

`/en/` is sub folder in `https://example.com` when user types `https://example.com/en/index.html` they should be redirected to `https://example.com/en/`

I have used the following code but it is redirecting to `https://example.com`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://example.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ http://example.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think it's happening due to your browser caches. Clear your cache and try again with your rules.

Comment: @starkeen thanks for the response I did clear the cache and tried but the result is same

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file? What are you intending to match with the captured subpattern (`(.*)`) in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_?

Comment: @MrWhite inside the `https://example.com/en/` path, actually there are 2 `.htaccess` one is in `https://example.com/` and one is in  `https://example.com/en/`

Comment: You need to identify where that redirect is coming from, as it doesn't appear to be from the code you posted. You may have a conflict with other directives, including the parent `.htaccess` file. Please include the complete contents of these files in your question. Your directives also reference `http`, whereas your description only references `https`? Also, please clarify that it is just `/en/index.html` that you want to redirect (as stated in your question). Your directives are doing more than this.

Comment: @MrWhite it was just a typo i had to replace `http` with `https`, thanks a lot

Comment: Are you saying that replacing `http` with `https` resolved this problem?! (If so, that would seem to suggest you have a problem with your HTTP to HTTPS redirect?)